# Installing Spritebuilder from source

Tags: github, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am trying to install spritebuilder but since it is no longer on the app store I have to do it through github.  I ran the following code from the readme file on github.

```
git clone https://github.com/apportable/SpriteBuilder
cd SpriteBuilder
git submodule update --init --recursive
cd scripts
./build_distribution.py --version 1.x
```

but it keeps returning the error: 

Testing failed:
    Error: There is no SDK with the name or path '/Users/*username*/SpriteBuilder/scripts/SpriteBuilder/SpriteBuilder/macosx10.9'

** TEST FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

Am I doing something wrong? I went into the build folder despite the error and the .app is not able to be opened, saying it may be incomplete or corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by downloading Spritebuilder from a mirror hosting site.